# website background color different in different computer?

Tags: colors, background, web, mismatch

We have put the orange-yellow color (#FFCF21) background for the website http://sblpl.com. But in our client system it displays as very light Yellow and it does not look good at all.

What might be the reason for this? Than

Answer (score 1):

This could be caused by a variety of reasons.

One that I could think of at the top of my head would be that your client's monitor renders the color differently than on the monitor you are using.

Also, your client's browser may be rending it differently from your browser due to the color profile settings.